# Saving and reading a file into a data table - C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datatable

I am new to this so bear with me. 
I am trying to create an application that can open a file, load it and then populate the data into a table. 
I have managed to hardcode it to the test file I wanted but now need to be able to open any file of the same extension.

The code I have so far is included. 
Appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction :) 
Thanks, Jo

```
   OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();

   private void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       ofd.Filter = "evtx|*.evtx"; //Only allows evtx file types to be seen and opened 
       if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) //Opens the file dialog on button click
       {
           this.fileNameTextBox.Text = ofd.FileName;
           saveFileNameTextBox.Text = ofd.SafeFileName;                
       }
   }

   private void loadFileButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       var dt = new DataTable();
       dt.Columns.Add("Level");
       dt.Columns.Add("Logname");
       dt.Columns.Add("Event ID");
       dt.Columns.Add("Date and Time");

       using (var reader = new EventLogReader(@"C:\Users\Jason\Desktop\Event logs\Security.evtx", PathType.FilePath))
       {
           EventRecord record;
           while ((record = reader.ReadEvent()) != null)
           {
               using (record)
               {                       
                   dt.Rows.Add(record.Level, record.LogName, record.RecordId, record.TimeCreated.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy tt:hh:mm:ss"));              
               }
           }
       }

       tblLogViewer.DataSource = dt;
   }
```

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: Easiest method : dt.WriteXml(fileName);

Comment: @MariusBancila - I am trying to find a way of not only having the Security.evtx file being read, the application needs to be able to allow other .evtx files to be opened. I hope that makes sense, if not I will try to elaborate :)

Comment: Thank you @jdweng, I will have a try :)

Comment: Hello @Jolene, did you try using the `saveFileNameTextBox.Text` like that: 
`using (var reader = new EventLogReader(saveFileNameTextBox.Text, PathType.FilePath))` ?

Comment: @NickPolyderopoulos - I have not tried that yet but it does make sense, thank you so much. Will try it now :)

Comment: @NickPolyderopoulos - Unfortunately it did not work. Error - System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogNotFoundException

Comment: @Jolene sorry I took the wrong textbox. You should use the `fileNameTextBox` textbox as @BACON says in his answer.

Comment: @NickPolyderopoulos - Thank you, makes sense now! Appreciate all the support :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what your issue is, you are prompting for a file in `Button3_Click()` with...

```
if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) //Opens the file dialog on button click
{
    this.fileNameTextBox.Text = ofd.FileName;
    saveFileNameTextBox.Text = ofd.SafeFileName;                
}
```

...but then in `loadFileButton_Click()` you are using a different path to construct an `EventLogReader`...

```
using (var reader = new EventLogReader(@"C:\Users\Jason\Desktop\Event logs\Security.evtx", PathType.FilePath))
{
```

You are already saving the selected file's path to `fileNameTextBox.Text`, so just pass that property to the `EventLogReader` constructor instead...

```
using (var reader = new EventLogReader(fileNameTextBox.Text, PathType.FilePath))
{
```

Note that `loadFileButton_Click` assumes that `ofd` has previously been displayed and accepted (not canceled).  Without knowing what your different buttons are, it might be better to create and use your `EventLogReader` immediately after successfully prompting for an input file...

```
if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) //Opens the file dialog on button click
{
    this.fileNameTextBox.Text = ofd.FileName;
    saveFileNameTextBox.Text = ofd.SafeFileName;                

    using (var reader = new EventLogReader(ofd.FileName, PathType.FilePath))
    {
        // Use reader...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This makes perfect sense and I have learned from it! Really appreciate the support :)